# Access modifier on abstract classes

Tags: c#, abstract-class, access-modifiers

If I have an abstract class like

```
public abstract class Player
{
    //fields
    private Sport _sport;

    //properties
    protected Sport Sport
    {
        get { return _sport; }
        set { _sport = value; }
    }      
}
```

Is this protected access modifier redundant since abstract cannot be instantiated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this protected access modifier redudant since abstract cannot be instantiated?

No, absolutely not. Consider:

```
Player player = new FootballPlayer();
Sport sport = player.Sport;
```

That would be valid if `Sport` were declared as a public property rather than protected. Of course, that may actually be what you *want*, but currently only code in derived classes (and within `Player` itself) can access the `Sport` property.

Note that your entire property would be simpler as an equivalent [automatically implemented property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) though:

```
protected Sport Sport { get; set; }
```

Or to allow public getting but protected setting:

```
public Sport Sport { get; protected set; }
```

Comment: `+1` for pointing out differing protection levels on getter and setter.  Also, keep in mind automatically implemented properties is [C# 3.0 and above](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx#csharp3.0overview_topic22).

Comment: @MikeChristensen: No, different access levels were introduced in C# 2. C# 3 introduced automatically implemented properties, but that's a different feature.

Answer (score 5):

No, `protected` in abstract class is not redundant because it makes the derived-implementing classes to "have"-derive:

```
protected Sport Sport
```

Instead of:

```
public Sport Sport
```

And if you used `private` or removed the modifier completely, then `sport` would be visible only for the abstract class itself.

For example:

```
public abstract class Player
{
    // Changed to auto property to save some key strokes...
    protected Sport Sport { get; set;}
}

public RealPlayer : Player
{
    public void Foo(Sport sport)
    {
        this.Sport = sport; // Valid
    }
}
```

In some other class...

```
var realPlayer = new RealPlayer();
realPlayer.Sport // Compilation error.
```

Comment: Holy crap I have more upvotes than Jon Skeet, probably not for long... :)

Comment: To be honest, I don't quite understand what you *mean* by "it makes the derived-implementing classes to have"...

Comment: @JonSkeet. I meant they derived the property with the `protected` modifier, I thought it was clear from the question.

Comment: It sounded to me like you expected the derived classes to *redeclare* the member. The member itself still belongs to the abstract class; it's inherited just like normal. It seems like other people find your answer clearer than I do though, which is fine :)

Comment: @JonSkeet. Thanks for the feedback, is it clearer now? Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -2):

```
abstract class ProgressNotesDetail
{

}

 internal class ProgressNotes : ProgressNotesDetail
{

}
```

Default Access modifier in Abstract class---- Internal